# The '%j' format specifier

Tags: c

During one of my lectures, my professor opened the wrong coding example (it seemed to be for a more advanced class) and before he switched to correct one, I caught a glimpse of a `%j` format specifier.

The small glimpse of code looked sorta like any other `printf()` statement:

```
printf("%ju\n", numbers[i]);
```

I've tried looking for an answer on duckduckgo and the stackoverflow search engine but for some reason I can't find any mention of it.

**For example:** https://www.tutorialspoint.com/format-specifiers-in-c  **No mention of `%j` whatsoever.**

Anyone knows why this might be the case?

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364486/conversion-specifier-ju): Defined in the C99 standard as `j — Speciﬁes that a following d, i, o, u, x, X, or n conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to intmax_t or uintmax_t.`

Comment: "I've tried looking for an answer " --> Instead look for the C spec: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4233925/2410359

Comment: Or simply consult [man 3 printf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)